# Python endswith() function cannot avoid copying .py file

Tags: python, tuples, copying

I am trying to copy some files based on extensions. My target is to copy everything except the extensions that are in my `ext_to_avoid` variable. However, I am failing miserably as it copies the .py files which I don't want to. I know that endswith requires 1-D variable or tuple to work.

Part of my script is given below:

```
x = os.getcwd()
ext_to_avoid = (".xml", ".bat", ".py", ".txt");
list_of_files_to_copy = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(x):
  for name in files:
    if not any([name.endswith(x) for x in ext_to_avoid]):
        print(os.path.join(root,name))
        list_of_files_to_copy.append(os.path.join(root,name))
```

I am not sure what's wrong with it. Could anyone point me to the right direction?

Kindest Reagrds,

Comment: You don't neet to use semicolon ";" to end lines.

Comment: ya my bad. Updating the code snippet :)

Comment: I mean, its not "wrong", just that Python ignores the semicolons at the end.

Comment: ya...my bad that I am not adopting good practice lolz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many file extensions to check against. Since the function "`endswith`" accepts a single string as an argument, given a single `name` you need to test it against each `ext`:

```
matches = False
for ext in ext_to_avoid:
    if name.lower().endswith(ext):
        matches = True
        break
if not matches:
    # ...
```

A simpler one liner can be:

```
if not any([name.lower().endswith(ext) for ext in ext_to_avoid]):
    # ...
```

**EDIT**: Well, it seems that [`str.endswith`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) will also accepts a `tuple`. Meaning that your original code was correct; try checking agains lowercase always:

```
if not name.lower().endswith(ext_to_avoid):
    # ...
```

Comment: Sorry, but your one liner doesn't work. Updated my code snippet

Comment: *str.endswith()* will also accept a tuple of extensions.

Comment: I know why it didn't work - idtiotic vision!! looked at the first line where I actually executed the script!!!!! grrr...thanks @vz0

Comment: @hagubear updated answer. Seems that you're using windows, Try converting the string to also lowercase first.

Comment: @vz0 don't worry. it works! as I said, I was being an idiot and checking the first line where the script was executed, hence my complaint about .py file.

Comment: Good to know `endswith` accepts tuple. Nice question and nice answers.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your original code and it works fine:

```
import os

x = os.getcwd()
ext_to_avoid = (".xml", ".bat", ".py", ".txt");
list_of_files_to_copy = [];
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(x):
  for name in files:
    if (name.endswith(ext_to_avoid)) is False:
        print(os.path.join(root,name))
        list_of_files_to_copy.append(os.path.join(root,name))
```

One nit.  It is preferred to write:

```
if not name.endswith(ext_to_avoid):
```

instead of:

```
if (name.endswith(ext_to_avoid)) is False:
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid extra variable usage you can do:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(x):
    for name in files:
        for ext in ext_to_avoid:
            if name.lower().endswith(ext):
                break
        else:
             # ...
```